# 'calc' in while loop causes undefined variable error in bash script

Tags: macos, bash, while-loop, calculator

The following code is a snippet from a larger bash script I'm writing to parse through a sequence of amino acids and carry out calculations based on specific pairs. For simplicity, I have shortened it and made it self contained - but the problem I'm coming up against is that if I run the example test calculation "calc ....." line - (which is commented out below,) I get a "... is undefined" error - which refers back to the variable fed into the while-read loop. Perhaps this is to do with subshells and/or variable accessibility but I'm stumped as to the solution, especially as I have similar scripts which work.

Any help would be appreciated. - Also, I'm running this in a mac OSX terminal.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Set input
Seq=HTCHMAREQEMNMHG
SeqMAX=${#Seq}

#set start position for read
Pos=1

#Analyse sequence
echo -e "\nReading: $Seq "

#Read sequence, one character at a time 
while  read -r -n1 Res ; do

    #If Res variable has hit a "blank", then move on
    if [[ $Res = "" ]] ; then

        break

    #Else, if Res variable is the first     
    elif [[ $Pos = "1" ]] ; then

        #Calculate rate

        #UNCOMMENTING THIS LINE CAUSES ERROR
        #calc 9 + 10

            echo "$Left $Right"
            Pos=$((Pos+1))
            Left=$Res

        #Else, if Res variable is the last  
        elif [[ $Pos = $SeqMAX ]] ; then

            Left=$Res
            Right=xC
            ###CALC............
            Pos=$((Pos+1))
            echo -e "$Left $Right"  

        #Finally, if charcter is internal       
        else 

            Right=$Res
            echo "$Left $Right"
            Left=$Res
            Pos=$((Pos+1))

        fi

done < <(echo $Seq)

exit
```

Comment: Ignoring for the moment why you are trying to do data processing in `bash`, where is `calc` defined? What is the *exact* error message?

Comment: calc is a command line calculator tool that I have installed due to it's ease of use with higher functions: http://sourceforge.net/projects/calc/  but I'm open to suggestions if you know a better one which won't throw this error. As for the exact error message, - with the code as I've supplied it, it is ""TCHMAREQEMNMHG" is undefined".

Comment: Is `calc` reading from standard input? The string it claims is undefined is what's left on standard input after your `read` consumes the first character. Perhaps `calc 9 + 10 < /dev/null` will make a difference. Or are you using a different call to `calc` that you aren't showing?

Comment: Thanks - yes adding < /dev/null does make a difference! Would you mind explaining a little, or pointing to another source, as to why that works? Thanks again!

Comment: `calc` inherits its standard input from the `while` loop, the same as `read`, so both are reading from the `<( echo $Seq )`. As to *why* `calc` reads from standard input, you'd have to consult its documentation.

Comment: Your version of `calc` might handle the `-p` flag (to disable prompt). Use it: `calc -p "9+10"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `calc` reads from standard input, so you need to prevent it from consuming data from the stream provided to the `while` loop intended for the `read` command:

```
calc 9 + 10 < /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing: '

Try:

calc '9 + 10'